# Duda acerca de como entender div y como los elementos trabajan juntos en html

Tags: html, html5

Si hay varios divs anidados y hasta adentro de ellos hay un elemento section, esto no causaria problemas al momento de que el navegador interprete la pagina ya que al comenzar a leer body se encontraria con un div y le restaria importancia a lo que hay dentro de el o continuaria leyendo la pagina?

Asi de esta manera:

```html
<body>



<header>
   <h1>Hablando de comida con Juan Leiva</h1>
</header>

<div>
   <div>
     <div>
         <section>
              <h2>Frutas y verduras</h2>
              
              <p>Las frutas y verduras son nutritivas para el ser humano</p>
              
              <p>Las personas del campo cultivan frutas para venderlas en grandes cantidades</p>
         </section>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 
 
 <div>
   <div>
     <div>
         <section>
              <h2>Carne</h2>
              
              <p> la carne nutre nuestros huesos y es muy deliciosa de digerir</p>
         </section>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 
</body>
 

 
 </body>
```

No afectaría que hayan tantos divs antes de llegar a un elemento semántico?

Suponiendo que el navegador, usa las secciones para agarrarlas una por una para hacerle un resumen de contenido a una persona que usa un screen reader para que así esta persona pueda saltar a diferentes secciones de nuestra pagina fácilmente. No afectaría el hecho de que hay varios divs antes de llegar a elementos section que si representan información valiosa por decirlo de alguna forma?

O es como tener un word como pintadas y bordes antes de llegar a la información, las pintadas y bordes podrían ser los divs y ya nuestros temas y párrafos, imágenes etc seria la información que lee la gente, el navegador obviaría esas decoraciones, igual harán que el documento se vea bonito pero va viendo el contenido div a div y cuando se tope con un grupo de secciones o una sección la interpretara de manera debida y no habrá ningún problema?,

Es como si un profesor ve todas las decoraciones bonitas y en los contenidos que tengamos en un trabajo académico pero igual terminara leyendo lo que si importa?, seria como decorar el contenido con todos esos divs, lo del contenido se fusiona con un div y se construye informacion con una capa coloreada y luego el otro div con el anterior que mencione y asi?

Se va estructurando asi la informacion en una pagina? Aunque haya pintadas bonitas, esas pintadas bonitas con informacion forman una unidad y el navegador mirara a esa parte de la unidad que le sirve (como parrafos, encabezados y esos elementos)?

El hecho de que haya divs en el exterior no significa que lo que tengan adentro no sea importante de ir a leer porque mas bien estructuran eso de adentro formando una sola cosa y al final se leerán las cosas que si importan?

Incluso si dentro de un elemento semántico como section hay divs, lo puedo tomar que hay decoraciones dentro del contenido, por ejemplo un párrafo con un borde bonito, podría interpretarse como un párrafo con borde bonito (una sola cosa), igual se procede a leer el párrafo mas allá de sus decoraciones?

¿Hay una parte de la información decorada individualmente (un párrafo con un div afuera) en vez de haber sido decorada generalmente pero igual se lee y el navegador usara lo que se lee para ofrecer accesibilidad por poner un ejemplo?

¿Es correcto verlo así, así podría ver el código que puse anteriormente?

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente no se utilizan muchos elementos dentro de otros, de forma que llegue el punto en que sea cargado más costosamente por el DOM.

> **DOM** permite el acceso dinámico a través de la programación para acceder, añadir y cambiar dinámicamente contenido estructurado en documentos.

Lo que no has tenido en cuenta es que a medida que agregas elementos dentro de otros, la estructura va perdiendo sentido. El hecho de que haya tags con nombres característicos como `section`, `header` o `footer` es principalmente para evitar lo que tú estás diciendo.

Carece de sentido agregar elementos `section` dentro de elementos `div` en la mayoría de los casos.

Te recomiendo que antes de realizar la estructura semántica de un sitio, consideres realizar primero la estructura visual. A partir de ahí, simplificar cada contenedor e ir añadiendo a medida que vas desde arriba hasta abajo.

Evitar el caos en un código HTML es fundamental, así como el uso justo y necesario de cada elemento. Evitar utilizar elementos `div`, siendo su uso solo y exclusivamente dado si se necesita realmente.

Espero haberte ayudado.